# Bootable device not being recognised by M1 mac

Tags: macos, multi-boot, windows-11, arm

I am not sure if this is the right site but I'm very stuck.

I've been trying to get a bootable drive onto my mac for a while, and I finally installed windows onto a micro SD card with enough storage. I went into boot options, but it wasn't recognised. Looking into the boot disk utils, it was there as a drive but not bootable.
Is this because an M1 mac as a whole can't boot from an external drive (I have reduced security on) at all (and thus why boot camp is disabled and not planned for ARM), or is it because its not a USB and a micro SD card.

I can't find any good youtube videos on the topic.

M1 Macbook Air 2020, running Ventura 13.0 reduced security. If you need the SD card details I can provide them.

*By install, I used a VM to run Rufus on windows to install an ISO of windows 11 onto the SD card. Microsoft Media Creation Tool doesn't recognise the SD card as a flash USB, well because it isnt. Should I go this option and buy a flash USB?

Comment: Windows requires an x86 processor, an M1 Mac has an ARM (non x86) processor. You'll need an ARM version of Windows.

Comment: Ahh right so the insider version? VHDX ending one?

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't show up as a bootable drive. Can M1 macs even have bootable drives or do I need a different medium?

Answer (score 1):

Apple silicon Macs can boot **macOS** from external drives, but note that the internal drive still needs to be operational and set up correctly at a low level, because some usually-hidden partitions on the internal drive of Apple silicon Macs are dedicated for use by iBoot, and can be thought of more like part of the boot ROM, rather than just a generic storage device.

Apple silicon Macs boot more like an iPhone than an x86 Mac; they use Apple's iBoot as the bootloader, not the early flavor of EFI that x86 Macs used, nor the more modern UEFI used by some x86 PCs and by Windows for ARM devices such as Microsoft Surface products as well as Project Volterra / Windows Dev Kit 2023.

I doubt there's a way at this time to install Windows for ARM in a way that iBoot would recognize it as a bootable OS, and I doubt Windows for ARM contains drivers for Apple silicon Macs, so the boot process wouldn't likely get very far anyway.

If you want to prove to yourself that your Apple silicon Mac can boot from an external drive, boot macOS from the internal drive, go to the Mac App Store and download the installer for macOS 13.x Ventura, then run it and tell it to install on the external drive. The external drive will likely need to use GPT (not MBR) as its partition scheme, and have an APFS partition.

Eventually, the [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org) project hopes to create the pieces necessary to boot [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org) natively on Apple silicon, but that's a work in progress.

It's conceivable that Apple and Microsoft may one day collaborate such that an Apple silicon Mac can natively boot Windows for ARM, but that hasn't happened yet.

It seems unlikely that Apple would build UEFI compatibility and Rosetta (the ability to run x86 instructions on Apple silicon with minimal performance penalty) into iBoot, so don't get your hopes up for running x86 OSes on close-to-bare-metal Apple silicon Macs.

At the time of this writing in November 2022, the only way to run Windows on an Apple silicon Mac is to run Windows for ARM inside Parallels Desktop running on macOS. macOS is the only OS that runs natively (i.e. on "bare metal") on Apple silicon hardware at this time.

Comment: There's [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) which is QEMU under the hood, ie an emulator not a virtualiser. [Sorry, way above my paygrade & I've never tried it.]